# Question about おきます

Tags: nuances, subsidiary-verbs

In the following sentences, what is the use of 'おきます'? And what is the difference in nuance if the sentences end without 'おきます'?

> 実家にいるうちに、母の料理をたくさん食べておきます。
>   お金があるうちに、ほしいものを買っておきます。